# How to access template instance data from autoform hook

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I declare a instance related dictionary.

```
Template.newMessage.onCreated(function () {
    var self = this;
    self.dict = new ReactiveDict('namedDic');
});
```

And access it via `Template.instance().dict.get()` in helpers and events.

However, autoform nests another template somewhere so my code to access this dict, no longer works:

```
AutoForm.hooks({
    serverCall: {
        before: {
            method: function (insert, update, current) {
                insert.foo = Template.instance().dict.get('foo'); <-- fails
                Meteor.call('serverCall', insert);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The doco doesn't seem to mention any way to access the parent template and I don't want to start guessing how many levels of parents it is.

If it makes any difference, my markup looks like this:

`+quickForm id='newMessage' schema='Schema.CustomMessage' type='method' meteormethod='serverCall'`

This is a bit of a A->B problem, what I want to do is just have autoform generate and validate a few fields, then I can insert some hidden values as part of a helper/event/hook before sending it off to the server.

Comment: yes, it pains me to read it in this format too, but i simply can't accept the best way to format code is to copy it to a new file, remove all my levels of nesting bar 1, then copy it back into the editor, otherwise i'd have to stand here all day spamming the spacebar...

Comment: That's like, 15 seconds of work... For a properly formatted code with color markup.

Comment: Agreed. I much prefer the ``` multiline code block syntax though, no need for extra formatting. In any case, I think I've spent about 6 formats worth of time on these comments. Kudos to Matthias for leading by example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure it is not a best approach, but I got it works by setting external variable in the same file scope.
Example:

```
var myNewMessageTemplate = null;

Template.newMessage.onCreated(function () {
    var self = this;
    self.dict = new ReactiveDict('namedDic');
    myNewMessageTemplate = self;
});

AutoForm.hooks({
    serverCall: {
        before: {
            method: function (insert, update, current) {
                insert.foo = myNewMessageTemplate.dict.get('foo'); <-- fails
                Meteor.call('serverCall', insert);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

What you need to be insure, that hooks and onCreate are in the same file, to be in the same scope.

Comment: Very Important point to be noted here is the `same file` and `same scope`.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in the past like so:

Define a helper to retrieve the ReactiveDict

```
Template.newMessage.helpers({
   foo : function () {
       return Template.instance().dict.get('foo');
   }
});
```

Then, I include that helper somewhere in my template.  Use `class="hidden"` if you don't want the user to see it.

```
<input type="text" class="hidden" value="{{foo}}" data-schema-key="foo" name="foo">
```

When quickForm submits, I believe it looks for all inputs with a data-schema-key attribute defined (or possibly it looks at the name, you can define both just to be certain.

Using this method, you should not need to define any hooks.

Comment: I'm using a hook to keep all my hidden field logic in one place. This sounds like I'd have to declare multiple helpers and hidden inputs for multiple fields. I'm currently making my reactiveDict file scoped so the hook can reference it.

Comment: Gotcha...well if that works, then sure why not.  One thing just occurred to me: you might be able to keep my solution to one helper that returns the entire dict, and one template that iterates over all the keys and creates hidden input for each.  Have never tried that though.

Comment: Another idea: pass the reactive dict as form attribute and access via this.formAttributes inside the hook.  I tend to try to avoid relying on file scoping since down the line I may do some refactoring and break things.

Comment: I did some more reading and have chosen to go with passing the whole data obj via an attribute. You can actually refer to the template via this.template.parent().parent().parent.....dict.get('foo') but levels of nesting is autoform dependent.